# apache solr over running lucene lib

Tags: java, apache, sockets, solr, lucene

1) I am working on product data from amazon product API and search with Apache Lucene 4.6.0, Due to some other code dependency i am not able to update JDK 1.6 to above and have already 7-8 GB Lucene Index.

So Basically i want to use solr api over my current working Lucene Library, Is it Possible, if it is not then what are the best solution for this situation.

2) I also want to implement Highlight and autocomplete through solr (if it will work over  my current Lucene Lib) or Lucene to make some intelligence in search *something like amazon search*.

3) Now i am using thread to get search query for Lucene from Socket but when i write back result to socket sometime it getting *java.net.SocketException: Connection Reset* *(Client From PHP and if i am using delay before closing socket from client then it is working Fine)*

4) Want to use position term vector so that search result should appear on keyword positioning order.

Thanks For your help/Suggestion